# Mysql query with count makes an error

Tags: mysql, odbc

The following mysql query...

```
SELECT a.*, b.*,
       ( 
            SELECT COUNT( * ) 
            FROM lp_units c 
            WHERE c.property_id = a.property_id 
        ) AS unitcount
FROM lp_property a,
     lp_property_confidential b
WHERE a.property_id = b.property_id
AND c.unitcount<= a.no_of_units
AND a.account_id = '1'
```

returns an error...

```
Unknown column 'c.unitcount' in 'where clause'
```

I think my query would be understandable. solve it to run....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The subquery has its own scope.

Comment: but i want to compare `unitcounts` please say any alternate solution @Adam

Comment: To extend on Adam's comment: put the check in the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `c.unitcount`. Just `unitcount`. `unitcount` is not a column of `c` but rather of the temporary table generated by the subquery.

However, this query is probably better written as a join anyway.

Try this query

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.*,
  COUNT(c.property_id) as unitcount
  FROM lp_property a
  JOIN lp_property_confidential b ON a.property_id = b.property_id
  JOIN lp_units c ON c.property_id = a.property_id
  WHERE
  a.account_id = '1'
  GROUP BY a.property_id
  HAVING unitcount <= a.no_of_units
```